# How to fix error "Can not resolve write order " when deleting user in Shopware 6?

Tags: admin, shopware6

When trying to delete a user, we are getting the error:

"Can not resolve write order for provided data. Remaining write order classes: user, user_config, media" when trying to delete a user in the Shopware 6 admin panel.

The error looks pretty programmer-specific so I am posting on StackOverflow.

Does that mean there is still data assigned to the user or is it a programming error?

[image: Can not resolve write order for provided data. Remaining write order classes: user, user_config, media]

How can we delete this user? Do we have to reset the user assignments via SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug that we fixed with 6.5. Here the link to the ticket: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-22262.

For now to be able to delete the user you can manually delete the profile image of the user (that was the root issue in the linked ticket).

Otherwise unset all the `userId` columns in the media table for the user you want to delete to null manually, that should solve the issue as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. The user does not have a profile image though. I even uploaded a cat and deleted it, still not working. But the user might "own" other media - that is what you probably mean?

Comment: SQL query for convenience `update media set user_id = null where user_id = 0x..........;`

Comment: Yep that's what i meant, the user "owns" all media the user uploaded